# yadfc date range filter with a column with a date format ( momentjs 'lll' ) is not working

Tags: yadcf

I have a DataTable with a column for date and time with momentjs format 'lll', the date range filter is not working.

```
{
   column_number : 4,
   filter_type: 'range_date',
   date_format: 'M d, yyyy',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bootstrap date picker, with the following setup (requires https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker files)

```
{
   column_number : 4,
   filter_type: 'range_date',
   datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker',
   moment_date_format: 'M d, yyyy',
   datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'
}
```

Comment: I have done it by using data-sorting and data-filtering DataTables attributes plus using your `html5-data` configuration.